# Is there a way to calculate retention rate with window function (sql)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table called 'orders" where I can find "customer_id" and "order_date"
From 01/04/2019 to 01/25/2019 we modified our interface and we want to see the impact on the retention rate.
To calculate the retention rate, I want to find all the customers who ordered between the 01/04/2019 and the 01/25/2019 and find how many of them reordered in the 30 days following their first order.

I tried to create a query to get this data using window function (amazon redshift) but I couldn't manage to find the solution.

```
SELECT customer_id, FIRST_VALUE(order_date IGNORE NULLS) 
over (partition by customer_id order by order_date asc rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) AS first_order,
NTH_VALUE(order_date, 2)
over(partition by customer_id order by order_date desc
rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) AS second_order
FROM il_country_sg.v_fct_orders
WHERE order_date between '20190104' AND '20190226'
GROUP BY customer_id, order_date
```

Here is what I tried to do.
My issue is that I get the two latest dates when I use the FIRST_VALUE and NTH_VALUE (2) functions.

I would need to use the LAST_VALUE and NTH_VALUE (n-1) functions but I don't know how to do.
Maybe you have a better solution to help me :)

Thank you and have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

> I want to find all the customers who ordered between the 01/04/2019 and the 01/25/2019 and find how many of them reordered in the 30 days following their first order.

You can use `lead()`.  Logic such as this should get you the first order for customers that meet the conditions in your question:

```
SELECT fo.*
FROM (SELECT fo.*,
             LEAD(fo.order_date) OVER (PARTITION BY fo.customer_id ORDER BY fo.order_date) as next_order_date,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fo.customer_id ORDER BY fo.order_date) as seqnum
      FROM il_country_sg.v_fct_orders fo
      WHERE fo.order_date >= '20190104'
     ) fo
WHERE order_date < '20190226' AND
      seqnum = 1 AND
      DATEDIFF(day, orderdate, next_order_date) <= 30;
```

You can use a subquery or CTE to get a count of such customers.

Comment: Thank you! The LEAD() function is actually very useful thank you! I tried to run the query but it failed. This is my error message : [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near ")". It refers to the ")" here `WHERE fo.order_date BETWEEN '20190104' ) fo`. Do you have any idea how to solve it please?